# how to shrink my celery-worker docker image?

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

I am running Django application on ECS and I am trying to optimize the size of Docker containers.

Below are my Dockerfiles that I am using to build django-app, celery-worker and celery-beat services on ECS. CMD are inserted in ECS task definition.

The problem I have is that the size of celery worker container exceeds 1 GB and with enabled autoscalig it takes around 5 minutes to create new task in ECS service, to build and deploy the container. It is not a problen when deploying whole application but it is probmematic when I want to autoscale my app and I need to wait 5 minutes for new task so celery can run another tasks. Concurrency is set up to 3 and I cannot put higher number because my tasks are heavy and last around an hour (each).

How can I optimize the size of celery Dockerfile and the way in is being built and deployed on ECS?

Dockerfile for Django:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV DockerHOME=/home/app/web
ENV GitHubToken=ghp_***

RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME

WORKDIR $DockerHOME

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . $DockerHOME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN pip install git+https://github.com/ByteInternet/pip-install-privates.git@master#egg=pip-install-privates

# install library from my private repository
RUN pip_install_privates --token $GitHubToken $DockerHOME/requirements.txt

# expose the port where the Django app runs
EXPOSE 8000
```

Dockerfile for celery-worker and celer-beat

```
FROM python:3.9
  
ENV DockerHOME=/home/app/web
ENV GitHubToken=ghp_***

RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
  
WORKDIR $DockerHOME

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 
COPY . $DockerHOME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install netcat &&  apt-get -y install gettext

RUN pip install git+https://github.com/ByteInternet/pip-install-privates.git@master#egg=pip-install-privates

RUN pip_install_privates --token $GitHubToken $DockerHOME/requirements.txt

# install playwright dependencies for chromium and firefox
RUN playwright install --with-deps chromium firefox
RUN playwright install-deps
```

requirements.txt

```
django==4.0.7
django-jazzmin==2.5.0
python-dotenv==0.21.0
django-celery-beat==2.3.0
django-celery-results==2.4.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
django-enum-choices==2.1.4
amazoncaptcha==0.5.2
fake-useragent==0.1.11
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.3.4
pymongo==4.2.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
pytest==7.2.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
pip-install-privates==0.6.3
whitenoise==6.3.0
django-filer==2.2.4
datetime==5.1
boto3==1.26.139
playwright==1.33.0
playwright-stealth==1.0.5
PyYAML==6.0
Scrapy==2.4.1
scrapy-fake-useragent==1.4.4
git+https://github.com/user/engine.git
```

Comment: Do you need both chromium and firefox? Can you use `FROM python:3.9-slim` instead? If not can you install the missing dependencies for using slim manually? Have you considered using mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.35.0-jammy instead? I would have tried to build it myself, but I don't have your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: thanks for comment @AndréC.Andersen. Yes I need both unfortunately because some celery tasks are using chrominium and some firefox.

Comment: ["Best practices for writing Dockerfiles"](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) from the **Docker docs** is a good place to start.

Comment: As you've shown the Dockerfiles there aren't super-obvious space savings to me.  I might consider using a multi-stage build, especially to avoid compromising your GitHub access token, but you're not doing things like installing a C toolchain that need lots of space only in a build stage.  Do you know where the space is going; do you actually need all of the Python dependencies you list?